# UITableViewController scrolling doesn't work in a container view controller

Tags: ios, scroll, uitableview, containers

I implemented simple UITableViewController and checked out scrolling of it works well if I make it root view of a UINavigationController.

The problem occurs when I added the table view controller to a container view controller like this:

```
[self addChildViewController:myTableViewController];
[self.view addSubview:myTableViewController.tableView];
[myTableViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This code works well except the scrolling problem.

When I try to scroll it, it is dragged slightly and returns to first position.
I can even see the table cells below the screen when I drag the table view, but it returns to the original state after I get off my finger.

Is there anyone who have been adding UITableViewController to a container?

**Update** After some digging, I found that it didn't work because the table view has long enough height. Now I can do scroll after setting frame size of the table view like this;

```
[self addChildViewController:myTableViewController];
[myTableViewController.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 44.0f, 320.0f, 100.0f)];
[self.view addSubview:myTableViewController.tableView];
[myTableViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Although there is another problem that the auto-resized height of the table view is improper, it looks better to make it another question.

Comment: Joybro, I tried building a project just like yours but I am not able to reproduce the issue. What are you adding the tableview controller to. Can you show more code.

Comment: @Srikanth thx for your comment. Now I can see the scroll bar after setting frame size of the client table view. I'm not sure this is the right way or I'm missing something.

Comment: @Srikanth The container controller view is just a subclass of UIViewController has a custom view. And it is a root view controller of an navigation controller.

Comment: @Srikanth In short, the `self` is a UIVIewController has a custom view and a subview(tableview), and is root view controller of a navigation controller.